# Flutter TextFormField Mask

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter and I am not able to apply a `CPF` and `CNPj mask`, so that when the input digits pass the required `CPF` size it changes to the`CNPj` mask. In this case the CPF mask is:

> XXX.XXX.XXX-XX and that of CNPj is XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX

Comment: use new MaskedTextController(mask: '000.000.000-00') from plugin flutter_masked_text

Answer (score 2):

A better solution to use default Flutter TextField is this:

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter#-readme-tab-

```
final maskCpf = MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: "###.###.###-##", filter: {"#": RegExp(r'[0-9]')});
final maskCNPJ = MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: "##.###.###/####-##", filter: {"#": RegExp(r'[0-9]')});
```

In the TextField:

```
TextField(inputFormatters: [maskCpf])
TextField(inputFormatters: [maskCNPJ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and found the solution using the [mask_shifter](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_shifter) plugin, which is very simple to use.